# How do i remove non vowels from a given string

Tags: python

I am not getting how to remove non vowels from a string

I know only how to remove vowels from string using regex

```
import re
st='adfgaweio'
re.sub('[aeiou]','',st)
```

if I give it as not -> `re.sub(!'[aeiou]','',st)` it throws error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `[^aeiou]` where `^` is the not operator

```py
import re

st = 'adfgaweio'
st = re.sub('[^aeiou]','',st)
# st now equals "aaeio"
```

Comment: I also recomend using [this site](https://regexone.com/) to learn some regex. It's really useful

Answer (score 0):

You could use translate (should run faster than re):

```
vowelsOnly = str.maketrans("","","bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz")

st = 'adfgaweio'
print(st.translate(vowelsOnly)) # aaeio
```

The 3rd parameter of maketrans defines characters to remove. Placing all consonants there makes the translate function remove non-vowel letters.  Note that this only covers lowercase letters. You would need to add the uppercase consonants to be case insensitive.

Comment: can you add explaination why you have written b z letters and what is the purpose for it

Answer (score -1):

You could also try this

```
st = 'adfgaweio'
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']
for i in range(len(st)):
  if not (st[i] in vowels):
    curr_st = curr_st + st[i]
st = curr_st
print(st)
```